# matter.js | Fixed Update problem for applyForce

Tags: javascript, physics, matter.js

I am making a player movement with `applyForce` using matter.js.
I am checking for pressed keys and applying force to my character in my game loop, which is normally called 60 times per second. But the problem begins when FPS drops. If the loop is called only 30 times per second, how can I applyForce the same amount when FPS was 60?
Is there any analog of FixedUpdate like in Unity?

Comment: fascinating question. reminds me of the existence of physics bugs in games (Doom 2016 I think) which are based on player framerate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem in game development. One way you can solve this problem is instead of applying the same amount of force in every update, you can check a clock to see how much time has passed since the last update (e.g. call `performance.now()` in every update). Then multiply the amount of force you want to add by the amount of time that has passed.

I don't think this will work perfectly in all situations. Especially if you have small, fast moving objects, you might find objects clipping through each other. But I think this will be good enough for most cases, and you should be able to code it by hand.